# Can't insert into database using jQuery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner with jQuery and ajax. When I click on the add button, all the fields are empty. Then, I fill those fields in and when I click on the submit button, nothing happens. I don’t know what to do. Can anyone help me please?

When clicking on the add button:

```
$("#add").on("click", addSeries);

function addSeries() {

    $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/Serie/getAll", function(series) {
        series.length + 1;
        $("#txtSerieId").val(series.length + 1);
    });
}
```

When clicking on the submit button

```
$("#submit").on("click", submit);
function submit() {

    var serieJson = '{"serie_id":' + $("#txtSerieId").val() + ',';
    serieJson += '"name" : "' + $("#txtName").val() + '",';
    serieJson += '"language_id" : "' + $("#txtLanguage_id").val() + '",';   
    serieJson += '"genre_id" : "' + $("#txtGenre").val() + '",';     
    serieJson += '"network_id" : "' + $("#txtNetwork").val() + '"';      
    serieJson += '}';

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/Series/add",
        data: JSON.stringify(serieJson),
        dataType: "json",
        processData:false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json"
    },
        success: function(data) {
            getAllSeries();
        }, error: function(err) { 
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: If you could share the error or anything ? there may be any error on the server side also ?

Comment: Don't compose JSON like that; but given that you have, there's no especially no need to use `JSON.stringify` (which you don't need in the first place).

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.com/6aENVTB7

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry if nothing appears to happen -- with ajax, it's mostly occurring behind the scenes.  I find the browser's inspector tool to be incredibly helpful for troubleshooting these requests.

1. In most versions of Chrome and Firefox, hit either CTRL+SHIFT+I or F12 (Or find Inspector/Developer Tools in the browser menus) to open the inspector.
2. Switch to the Network view/tab/panel.
3. There is usually a filter labeled XHR - Click it to hide everything but your ajax request.  (So far, it's probably going to be empty)
4. Submit your ajax request.

At this point, if your code works, your should see a new post request appear in the network tab that you can click on to explore.  Every browser is a little different, but you should be able to see what parameters were sent to the server along with their their values -- and the server's response.  For example, if your server side code returned an error, you should be able to see it here.

If after making your ajax call you **don't** see anything appear in the network tab, it may be that the javascript/jquery code encountered an error before it could make the call.  The Inspector can help with that too! Try switching to the Console tab -- any javascript errors that occur should appear in this window.  *You may need to run your submit function again with the console open.*

Hope that helps point you in the right direction!  The inspector is an ajax requests best friend.  This article goes into a lot more detail on using it to troubleshoot: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

Answer (score 0):

Create object instead of appending values to the string.

```
function submit() {

    var serieJson = {
        serie_id: $("#txtSerieId").val(),
        name: $("#txtName").val(),
        language_id: $("#txtLanguage_id").val(),
        genre_id: $("#txtGenre").val(),
        network_id: $("#txtNetwork").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url:"http://localhost:8080/Series/add",
        data: JSON.stringify(serieJson),
        dataType: "json",
        processData:false,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json"
        },
        success: function(data) {
            getAllSeries();
        },
        error: function(err) { 
        }
    });
}
```